# How to embed pictures from Google Docs in new interface?

Tags: google-docs

Previously it was possible to get rendered bitmap URL from Google doc picture. But now they created a new degraded interface where I can't find such an option. I can only "share" image, but I want to embed it into page with `<img>` tag.

Is it possible or interface was degraded irreversible?

Answer (score 1):

At this time Google Docs inserted images doesn't have a URL that users could get from the edit view.

You could publish the document as a web page (see [Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)) and get the image URL from the source of the resulting web page. There are more alternatives like add the image to a Google Drawing. You will be able to publish it as a image so you will not have to look for its URL in the source of a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this problem on the [Biola University IT Services Confluence board](https://confluence.biola.edu/display/itservices/How+to+Embed+Images+from+Google+Drive+in+a+Web+Page).

Basically you need to build the following URL,

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILEID>
```

Where the `<FILEID>` is obtained by going to the Shared options of your Google Drive image, ensuring it is shared as Public (look in the advance sharing options) and copying the shareable link which will look something like this,

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/`**0ByvA2N_U0L32YkpZcEEzSlNnamM**`/view?usp=sharing`

the `<FILEID>` you need is in bold above, it is between the `...file/d/` and `/view..` part of the link.

So that your final embeddable link looks like,

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0ByvA2N_U0L32YkpZcEEzSlNnamM
```

which you can embed in an thml page for example with and `img` tag,

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0ByvA2N_U0L32YkpZcEEzSlNnamM"/>
```